# Using `Not` with `Delegate` - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I currently have something like this:

```
$(".jtable tbody td").not(".DeleteLicense").hover(
```

How can I use delegate with this? Something like

```
$("#resultContainer,#approvalContainer,#createNewContainer").delegate(".jtable tbody td....
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to move the negation in to your selector.

```
$("#resultContainer,#approvalContainer,#createNewContainer")
    .delegate(".jtable tbody td:not(.DeleteLicense)", "...", ...);
```

Note that the jQuery documentation recommends using the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function rather than the `:not()` selector in most cases, but I'm not sure if it is possible in this case.

If you're willing to use another approach, you may find that you could use the `.jtable tbody td` selector in your call to [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), and then use `if(!$(this).is(".DeleteLicense")) { ... }` in your event handler to only process elements that meet your criteria.

Comment: great example of how to use the not selector, didn't know that.

Comment: is there an advantage to using the latter vs. the former method?

Comment: In my opinion using the `:not()` selector makes the code cleaner and easier to understand. I don't know what the performance implications are for either approach, though. Using `.is` in the event handler makes things more complicated because your selector says one thing but your code does another.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$("#resultContainer,#approvalContainer,#createNewContainer").delegate(".jtable tbody td:not('.DeleteLicense')", "hover", function(eventObj) {
    // handler code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to try and use the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$("#resultContainer,#approvalContainer,#createNewContainer").delegate(".jtable tbody td:not('.DeleteLicense')", "hover", function(){ /* do stuff */});
```